# Skip lein uberjar when sources are unchanged?

Tags: clojure, cmake, leiningen

Is it possible to make `lein uberjar` not create a jar if no changes have been made since the previous jar was made?

Either as a feature of leiningen or with some bash scripting?

My specific use case is that I'm calling lein from within a CMake build system of a larger project.

```
execute_process(COMMAND lein uberjar
                WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

All the C++ sources are skipped if they haven't changed, but uberjars keep being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find command will allow you to find all files that are newer than another file.

A script built on that might look something like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

UBERJAR=*-standalone.jar

if [ -f ${UBERJAR} ]; then
     modified_files=$(find src project.clj -newer ${UBERJAR})

     if [ ${#modified_files} -eq 0 ]; then
         echo "Skipping uberjar because no files modified"
         exit 0
     fi  
fi  

lein uberjar
```

If your project has snapshot dependencies you will skip the check that determines whether you should update your snapshots from the central repo.

I suspect you'd be better off just taking the hit of building the uberjar everytime.

Comment: @Annan your edit is incorrect, the first arg to find is the directory from which to search, so adding project.clj there doesn't make sense.

Comment: Feel free to rollback the edit or modify it if you think I'm incorrect. I believe multiple paths can be passed to find as the first parameters, these paths can be directories, files or patterns.

Comment: Ok, Having actually tested what I said I stand corrected ;-) your mod works as expected. thanks!